# Question about symmetric spaces

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology

I'm a little confused with the following questions:

(1) Why does a symmetric space $M=G/K$ of compact type have $\mathcal{R}^M\geq 0$?

(2)Moreover, why does $\chi(M)\neq 0$ if and only if ${\rm rk}\ G={\rm rk}\ K$?

(3)For a symmetric space $M=G/K$ of compact type with dimension $4k+1$, why does Kervaire semi-characteristic $\sigma(M)\neq 0$ iff ${\rm rk}\ G={\rm rk}\ K+1$?
Where $$\sigma(M):=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2k}b_{2i} \mod 2,\quad  b_{j}:=\dim H^j(M;\mathbb{R})$$

Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://mathoverflow.net/a/242177/124862 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31198/curvature-of-a-lie-group. The same ideas can be used to compute the curvature tensors for $M$.

Comment: Could you please write down your idea? I have a difficulty in following the logic of your idea. Thanks a lot.@Kapil